# Does “can be” have an alternative that is not in the passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice, hypercorrection, software-bugs

I have been experimenting with different forms of grammar recently, and have enabled Verbose Grammar Checks in Microsoft Word to alert me when I am unknowingly using the passive voice.

I wanted to find an alternative to *can be* that is not in the passive voice. If possible can you alter the following sentence, to avoid the passive voice:

> C<sup>♯</sup> can be compiled natively.

Comment: One could argue that this is what passive voice is intended for.

Comment: You could say 'One can compile C# natively'.

Comment: The passive voice is not to be avoided.  Some languages specifically inflect their verbs for the passive voice, because of how incredibly beneficial it is.

Comment: @user61979: Yes, and the benefits are not to be gainsaid.

Answer (score 4):

The point about the passive voice is that it removes the subject of the active-voice version. It focuses the attention on the object (C#, in this case).

To convert to the active voice, the subject needs to be replaced. Or: you need to replace the subject.

> You can compile C# natively.
>   I can compile C# natively.
>   One can compile C# natively.
>   Those who are able to can compile C# natively.

In some cases, the passive voice is exactly right, and cannot realistically be converted to active voice.

The general rule with Microsoft's grammar checker is to take all its advice with a huge pinch of salt, and certainly tune its rules. For myself, I turn it off altogether.

Comment: Microsoft's grammar checker's advice should be taken with a huge pinch of salt, and its rules certainly tuned. It is considered best turned off, by some. Or, _Don't be overcome by passive resistance._